# Task.Factory.StartNew and main UI

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I am learning how Task works. I have always used the BackgroundWorker class or the
Threading.Thread class so I wanted to taste Task Factory.

In the following example I am building, I recover a

```
 Task<List<People>>
```

And assign it a "ContinueWith" that I expect to be called when the task has finished.

I have done some previous examples that were working awesome but this one freeze my

Main form UI when the application is launched. (I can not see difference with the
other examples I did who doesn't).

Do you know guys why my Main UI freezes?

PS: I know I declare

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheUI
```

on the Task declaration. I'm not using right now but I will later.

Thanks in advance:

Here is the code:

```
 private void PopulateList(List<People> list)
            {
                if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
                { 
                 listBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {

                     foreach (People item in list)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(item.name + " " + listBox1.Items.Add(item.surname));   
                    }

                 });
            }
        }



private Task<List<People>> GetPeopleListAsync(int PeopleNuber, int delaysecs)
        { 
         TaskScheduler scheUI = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            return Task<List<People>>.Factory.StartNew( () =>
                {
                    List<People> listado = new List<People>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < PeopleNuber; i++)
                    {
                        People people = new People
                        {
                            name = "Name" + i.ToString(),
                            surname = "Surname " + i.ToString()
                        };

                        Thread.Sleep(delaysecs * 200);
                        listado.Add(people);
                    }

                    return listado;


                },CancellationToken.None,
                 TaskCreationOptions.None,scheUI);

        }


 void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {


            Task<List<People>> task = GetPeopleListAsync(5, 10);
            task.ContinueWith(p => PopulateList(task.Result));
 }
```

Comment: How many cores does your PC have? As there is no guarantee that a task will run in a separate thread i am guessing that maybe everything is running in the same thread.

Comment: For debug purposes try to create the task with the following option System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning

Comment: Is there some reason you don't have a `using System.Threading.Tasks`?  It's really cluttering up your code to see it everywhere.

Comment: Yeah there is. Its my first example so I make sure I will always remember the namespaces ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are synchronizing the first task with the UI thread using:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheUI = System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

Remove the scheUI scheduler from the first task:

```
return System.Threading.Tasks.Task<List<People>>.Factory.StartNew( () =>
            {
                List<People> listado = new List<People>();

                for (int i = 0; i < PeopleNuber; i++)
                {
                    People people = new People
                    {
                        name = "Name" + i.ToString(),
                        surname = "Surname " + i.ToString()
                    };

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delaysecs * 200);
                    listado.Add(people);
                }

                return listado;


            });
```

You should add the synchronization to the second task that is executed in order to update your UI:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheUI = System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
task.ContinueWith(p => PopulateList(task.Result),CancellationToken.None,
                              TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously |
                              TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                              scheUI);
```

Comment: Should I declare the Task with: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.Default);  ?

Comment: I edited my answer. Don't need to use any TaskScheduler if you don't need it.

Comment: One more thing please. If sync os assigned to continuewith then the invokerequired is not needed right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You need the Invoke method from a control when working in a thread different than the UI.